# How do I change values of LAB colors in Illustrator using a script?

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to write a script in JS, that will run through all the objects in my file, and change their LAB color values (change L individually, A, and B).

I tried this code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
                
doc.swatches.getByName("MySwatchName").color.l = 42;
doc.swatches.getByName("MySwatchName").color.a = 40;
doc.swatches.getByName("MySwatchName").color.b = 2;
```

But it doesn't work. Changing the name of the swatch was possible, but not changing the color values.

I read [this article](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/illustrator-javascript-render-swatch-legend-lab-colour-values-incorrect/m-p/11437592) and now I wonder, might it be that what I am trying to do is impossible with the scripting API?

Comment: It look like it's impossible to do directly. But Carlo's code gives the hope (I can be wrong, though) that it can be done indirectly: Lab > convert to RGB > change RGB color by some formulae > convert back to Lab (or select nearest Lab color from a some predefined list). It's need further inquiry

Comment: As for 'predefined list of colors' it could be a simplest (and dumbest as well but working) solution by the way. Say, you can make a file-palette (not manually of course) with 50*50*50 = 125.000 Lab-color swatches, open the file by script and get from it the nearest swatch you need. I did something like this for Pantone colors.

Comment: Hi Yuri, thank you for the help, I did not run away, but still trying to figure out how to use Carlo's code for my needs. Do you know maybe what's the specific code to convert LAB color to CMYK and back again?

Comment: Okay, thank you for feedback. Let me know if you need a help.

Comment: I tried this code:
`var doc = app.activeDocument

swatchColor = doc.swatches.getByName('C');
const colorList = [swatchColor]
convertSampleColor(ImageColorSpace.LAB, colorList, ImageColorSpace.CMYK, ColorConvertPurpose.defaultpurpose);

alert("Code executed.");`
This code should just convert the swatch spot color from LAB to CMYK but it doesn't help. The alert message pops up, but no changes are made.

Comment: I tried a different code:
`var doc = app.activeDocument

var swatchColor = doc.swatches.getByName('C');
var CMYKvalues=swatchColor.color.spot.color;
swatchColor.color=CMYKColor;
swatchColor.color=CMYKvalues;
alert("Code executed.");`

Now, first of all, it converts the spot color to RGB for some weird reason.
Secondly, I found out that RGB/CMYK isn't accurate enough, for example L:90, A:90, B:90 and also L:91, A:90, B:90 will convert to the same RGB value, so it isn't accurate enough.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator's API has limited tools to manage Lab colors. As far as I can tell only spot Lab colors can be changes by script.

Here is the function that changes (or creates) Lab spot color with given name to given values (L, a, b):

```
function change_lab_spot_color(L,a,b,spot_name) {

    var lab_color = new LabColor();
        lab_color.l = L;
        lab_color.a = a;
        lab_color.b = b;

    try {
        var spot = app.activeDocument.spots.getByName(spot_name);
    } catch(e) {
        var spot = app.activeDocument.spots.add();
            spot.name = spot_name;
            spot.colorType = ColorModel.SPOT;
            spot.spotKind = SpotColorKind.SPOTLAB;
    }

    spot.color = lab_color;

    var spot_color = new SpotColor();
        spot_color.spot = spot;

}

// it will create the spot color 'test' (if there is no swatch with this name)
change_lab_spot_color(50,50,0,'test');

// it will change the values of the spot color 'test' to L50,a0,b50
change_lab_spot_color(50,0,50,'test');
```

Your artwork should be painted with spot Lab colors if you want to change the colors by script. Probably it's quite possible to recolor your artwork to spot Lab colors automatically with another script.